# how to get a client key and client root cert for connecting to CockroachDB from Java client

Tags: kubernetes, csr, cockroachdb

I have deployed a CockroachDB single instance cluster in my Kubernetes cluster on DO following this link https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-a-local-cluster-with-kubernetes.html.

I followed this link to generate a server.crt file from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster using the command:

```
kubectl get csr my-svc.my-namespace -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' \
| base64 --decode > server.crt
```

Not sure that gets me a client cert.
The following is my output for the command:

```
kubectl get csr

NAME                  AGE       REQUESTOR                                              CONDITION
default.client.root   44m       system:serviceaccount:default:my-release-cockroachdb   Approved,Issued
```

I need to connect to CockroachDB using my Java client.  How do I generate a client cert and key so I can access CockroachDB from Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple concerns here:

- the certificate you are requesting from the k8s PKI will not have any of the fields required
- the key format will not work for java clients

Let's address them one at a time:

**Requesting a client certificate from the kubernetes PKI**

A client certificate for user with CockroachDB must the subject's Common Name set to the username. eg: `CN=root`. This must also be properly configured to allow `Client Authentication` in the key usage.

In the [kubernetes docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-a-local-cluster-with-kubernetes.html#step-3-use-the-built-in-sql-client), we include an example to bring up a client within the same kubernetes cluster. The [config](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/blob/master/cloud/kubernetes/client-secure.yaml) for secure clients includes an init container that requests a client certificate and makes it available to the main job.

If your client is running in Kubernetes, I recommend adapting that config for your own client.

**Key format for java clients**

Java clients expect keys in PKCS#8 format, whereas the certificates output by both your command and the `request-cert` tool both output PEM encoded keys.

You can convert the key using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in client.myuser.key -out client.myuser.pk8
```

You can find more details on the [CockroachDB Build a Java app page](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.1/build-a-java-app-with-cockroachdb.html#step-4-convert-the-key-file-for-use-with-java).

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I want to download the ca.key and the ca.crt from my K8 for the CockroachDB.  Is there a way to do this using a command line in kubectl?

Comment: I got you Marc.  Thanks.